# Intel HD 3000, HDMI and 2560x1080

Tags: macos, display, hdmi, resolution

I recently purchased an ultra wide monitor, with a native resolution of 2560x1080.

This is great but it's only working with Windows !
Apple is limiting HDMI resolution to be no more than 1920x1080, for no reason at all. I read everywhere than I need to buy whatever cable or adapter and to use display port, but I just can't.
I also tried SwitchResX but same problem, resolutions over 1920x1080 are not available.

So I searched for a solution, and I found something interesting there : https://discussions.apple.com/message/25831860#25831860
It seems that increasing the framebuffer size will set bigger resolution available.

But I can't find any info about this with an Intel HD 3000. Is someone have any clue about where to begin ? I guess it's happenning in AppleIntelSNBGraphics but that file is quite big...

Another question I'm having is, is this still the case on Yosemite ? Because I'm on Mavericks and I could do the update if that might solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I finally found a solution :

1. Update to Yosemite.
2. Apply a patch to IOKit.framework : https://github.com/Floris497/mac-pixel-clock-patch
3. Enjoy 2560x1080 50Hz using HDMI cable